# How to raise OnPropertyChanged only for visible elements?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have very large grid. I want to use CheckBox "check/uncheck all" which will check/uncheck all rows. But it very slow, because there are to many invokes of OnPtopertyChanged event. How can I raise OnPropertyChanged event only for visible elements? Virtualization of rows is enabled.

Comment: You are challenging the fundamentals of WPF here. There's no easy way of doing that. Did you consider to use paging?

Comment: Paging can confuse is "check all" check all elements on all pages or only on current page.

Comment: how to you set check/uncheck of all rows? pls post this code

Comment: I just bind CheckAll command to checkbox in header and into this command set IsChecked property for all ViewModels which is related to rows in grid.

Comment: @Rover - Do you have your collection of objects wrapped or it's a plain Enumerable<T>?

Comment: how many rows did you have? i do the same in my apps and have no problems

Comment: I have 5 columns with checkboxes. 20000 rows. Please, don't ask why 5 columns, it's question for customers )) "Check All" checkbox should check all this checkboxes.

Comment: Ditch INPC and convert your models into DependencyObjects, as [DP bindings are the fastest in WPF.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx#HowDataBindingReferencesAreResolved).  Also, stop adding tags to your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First approach: Remove raising of OnPropertyChanged and add dataGrid.Items.Refresh();

Second approach: silently change properties and then

```
var rows = grid.FindChildren<DataGridRowsPresenter>().First() as DependencyObject;
int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(rows);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rows, i) as DataGridRow;
    (row.DataContext as IViewModel).Refresh();//Refresh invokes OnPropertyChanged 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

20000 rows are a lot :)

what happens if you disconnect your ItemsSource binding alter your list in your viewmodel and set the itemssource to the new checked list?

oterwise if they want 20000rows they can wait for it ;)

EDIT

if you dont change your itemssource you have to raise propertychanged for every item, otherwise you dont see the changes.

another way is to set the binding to null or new List

```
  this.MyGridItemsViewModelProperty = new List();//"disconnect" the binding to the grid for the all check/uncheck
```

then alter your real list with check/uncheck and set it back as the grid ItemsSource

```
   this.MyGridItemsViewModelProperty = myupdatelist;
```

grid

```
   <Grid ItemsSource="{Binding MyGridItemsViewModelProperty}" />
```

but i dont know if the second approach is faster, you should test it.

Comment: How can I disconnect and then connect the same DataSource? It refreshed only hidden elements. But it works pretty faster.

Comment: mhh you wrote check/unckeck is very slow - now you wrote is pretty fast? whats the real problem? maybe you should post your datagrid binding  xaml, trigger and your viewmodel.

Comment: Problem is in OnPropertyChanged. If I invoke it on every check for each element it works slow. It I remove it, it works fast, but UI doesn't show changes. So, I just need to refresh visible part of UI.

Comment: 20K rows looks scary by in actual fact it's not too bad for a single grid. It's hard to observe that volumes, but it's a different question.

Comment: @Rover that on its own won't fix your problem, you'll need more complex solution whereby your OnPropertyChanged will be re-evaled as the user will scroll the grid. It's gonna be a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks, it works faster then OnPropertyChanged, but i found another approach: dataGrid.Items.Refresh(). Can I refresh only data in rectangle? P.S. Hope @P.K will explain how to check IsVisible for DataGridRow item.

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this would be to have a `boolean IsVisible` property in ViewModel. If `IsVisible` returns `true` only then you can raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: The only problem is how to set those IsVisible flags for the virtualising grid:)

Comment: I was meant to say for your MV:)

Answer (score 0):

Update 1 I'm after creating a simple repro with 100K rows and it flyes on my low spec PC, could you check it on yours and confrim if it's fast enough? The project name's `GroupSelect` and then just copy/past stuff into the main window.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace GroupSelect
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded +=
                (o, e) => 
                {
                    this.DataContext =
                        new Model(100000);
                };
        }
    }

    public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool? isAllSelected = null;

        public Model(int itemCount)
        {
            this.Items =
                Enumerable.Range(1, itemCount).Select(t =>
                    new Item(this)
                {
                    Name = "n_" + t.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            this.IsAllSelected = false;
        }

        public List<Item> Items
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public bool? IsAllSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isAllSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.IsAllSelected != value)
                {
                    this.IsBatchUpdate = true; // updating

                    this.isAllSelected = value;

                    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.PropertyChanged(this,
                            new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsAllSelected"));
                    }

                    //
                    if (this.IsAllSelected.HasValue)
                    {
                        foreach (Item i in this.Items)
                        {
                            i.IsSelected = value.Value;
                        }
                    }

                    this.IsBatchUpdate = false; // updating
                }
            }
        }

        public bool IsBatchUpdate
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool isSelected = false;

        public Item(Model model)
        {
            this.Model = model;
        }

        public Model Model
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.IsSelected != value)
                {
                    this.isSelected = value;

                    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.PropertyChanged(this,
                            new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
                    }

                    if (!this.Model.IsBatchUpdate)
                    {
                        this.Model.IsAllSelected = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<Window x:Class="GroupSelect.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupSelect"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="g" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path='Items'}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, 
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsAllSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: The problem is that notification that all collection is changed doesn't take effect, while I don't change it at all. grid.ItemsSource = null; grid.ItemsSource = elements; - it doesn't work for visible rows but take affect to elements under scroll. Also, RaisePropertyChanged(() => Elements) doesn't work.